# Terraform variables and count from CSV

Tags: terraform

I'm making myself virtual machines from the CSV list. Currently it works for me to create virtual machines for all entries. I only need to create them for those that have in CSV in the maxview table have = 1. Is it possible? I try also with

```
 for_each     =  { for inst in local.instances : inst.node => inst } ? 1:0
```

but not results.

.csv

```
"node","node_ip","ipmi_ip","vmsystem","vmhost","node_id","maxview"
"s156","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","vmware","vmhost.example.com","15","1"
"s101","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","Proxmox","vmhost.example.com","","0"
```

main.tf

```
locals {

 instances = csvdecode(file("./data/sys-${local.environment}.csv"))
  vsphere_hn = {
    domain = "hn"
    dev1 = {                                
      app_datastores = ["sata_ssd_storage_140-1"]                                                                 
    }
    eu1 = {
     app_datastores = ["sata_ssd_storage_140-1"]
    }
  }

}


// VMs

module "vm-hn-maxview-maxview_vm" {

  count = length(local.instances)
  providers = {
    vsphere = vsphere.vcadmin
  }


  name       = "${local.instances[count.index].node}.${local.vsphere_hn.domain}.${var.dns_local_name[local.environment]}"
  annotation = "Managed by Terraform"

  dc        = var.vsphere_core_datacenter_name[local.environment]
  datastore = local.vsphere_hn[local.environment].app_datastores[count.index]

  template           = var.centos7_vsphere_template[local.environment].template
  resource_pool_vapp = vsphere_vapp_container.vm-hn-maxview-vapp.id

  customize_name   = "maxview"
  customize_domain = "${local.instances[count.index].node}.${local.vsphere_hn.domain}.${var.dns_local_name[local.environment]}"

  cpu_number           = 2
  num_cores_per_socket = 1
  ram_size             = 2048

  network = {
    "${var.network_vlan_maxview_name[local.environment]}" =  ["${var.network_address_prefix[local.environment]}.8.${local.instances[count.index].node_id}"] 
  }
  network_gateway = "${var.network_address_prefix[local.environment]}.9.254"
  network_submask = ["${var.network_address_submask_maxview[local.environment]}"]

  data_disk = {
    disk1 = {
      size_gb                   = 10,
      thin_provisioned          = false,
      data_disk_scsi_controller = 0,
    }
  }
}
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` expression lambda is close, but you need to add a conditional for the `maxview`:

```
# number to number comparison
for_each = { for inst in local.instances : inst.node => inst if tonumber(inst.maxview) == 1 }
# string to string comparison
for_each = { for inst in local.instances : inst.node => inst if inst.maxview == "1" }
```

This will filter your `map(object)` down to only the entries where `maxview` equals 1, and then the `for_each` meta-argument will cause iteration over only those entries. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#filtering-elements).

Comment: A small gotcha here is that all of the elements from `csvdecode` are strings, because CSV doesn't track type information, and `1 != "1"` so I'd expect the expression shown here to filter out _all_ the entries. `tonumber(inst.maxview) == 1` should do the trick, though.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Right, I did miss that implicitly in the documentation example where it was an `int` in the csv and then suddenly `string` in the HCL2. The asker also had it as a string in the csv anyway, so that is probably the worse oversight here. For some reason I thought `number` would have a constructor in HCL2, but yeah looks like using the function for type conversion (member of struct for number? no idea). What bothers me more is that upon second viewing any module argument that expects a `number` for `maxview` would need an implicit type conversion from `string`.