# Use for loop to fetch values from csv file using terraform

Tags: azure, for-loop, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a csv file which has few values. How to iterate through it using terraform. Need to use for loop for the same

```
locals {
    vnetlist = csvdecode(file("./title.csv"))
    datalist = ([for vnets in lookup(data.azurerm_resources.spokes, "resources", []) : lookup(vnets, "name")])
    finopslist = ([for r in vnetlist : r ])
}
```

This code is giving me the below error. The for loop throws error.
PS C:\Users\rmani\Documents\Ramya\Repo\FTest> terraform plan -var-file="subsc2.tfvars"
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on main.tf line 9, in locals:
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

My csv file is like this

[image]

datalist gives me the below values
regA
regB
regC

These values should be in the column region instead of us,er,ind

Comment: Can you provide actual file content, not  excel screenshot of it?

Comment: vnetname size region
usvnet 1 us
ervnet 2 er
indvnet 3 ind

Comment: This is the csv content. Kindly help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform variables and count from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377176/terraform-variables-and-count-from-csv)

Comment: I am still stuck i have made the below code change to export it to csv but still i am not able to send the data to a particular column and row of an existing csv

Comment: data "azurerm_resources" "spokes" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
}

locals {
    vnetlist = csvdecode(file("./title.csv"))
    vnetnames = ([for vnets in lookup(data.azurerm_resources.spokes, "resources", []) : lookup(vnets, "name")])
    finopslist = {for r in local.vnetlist : r.region => local.vnetnames }
    
}


resource "local_file" "vnetsupdated" {
  filename = "./billing.csv"
  content =  join("\n,,", local.vnetnames)
  
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195071/is-it-possible-to-send-terraform-output-data-to-particular-column-of-existinf-cs

This is something i am trying to achieve which i am not able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be (you forgot local keyword):

```
finopslist = ([for r in local.vnetlist : r ])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195071/is-it-possible-to-send-terraform-output-data-to-particular-column-of-existinf-cs